# Error in function RouteHandler in ./.cache/root.js:21

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, gatsby

I am trying create gatsby project without using CLI to understand how CLI generated pieces work. But I am getting following runtime error popup on the browser

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> One unhandled runtime error found in your files. See the list below to
> fix it:
>
> Error in function RouteHandler in ./.cache/root.js:21 Cannot read
> property 'Provider' of undefined
>
> ./.cache/root.js:21
>
> ```
>   19 | // Remove this in v3
>   20 | const RouteHandler = props => (
> > 21 |   <BaseContext.Provider
>      |   ^
>   22 |     value={{
>   23 |       baseuri: `/`,
>   24 |       basepath: `/`,
> ```

Directory structure

```
├── content
│   └── blog
├── gatsby-config.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── public
│   ├── page-data
│   │   ├── dev-404-page
│   │   │   └── page-data.json
│   │   └── index
│   │       └── page-data.json
│   ├── render-page.js
│   ├── render-page.js.map
│   └── static
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── header.js
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── images
│   └── pages
│       ├── blog.js
│       ├── index.js
│       └── page404.js
└── static
```

Given below are some important code files

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-from-scratch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "n/a",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^3.9.1",
    "gatsby-link": "^3.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.9.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: 'Gatsby Scratch'
    },
    plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-react-helmet']
}
```

layout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import Header from "./header";
import {graphql} from "gatsby";

const Layout = ({children, data}) => {

    if(children == undefined)
    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
                    meta={[{name: 'description', content: 'Sample Gatsby website created from scratch without using CLI generator'},
                        {name: 'keywords', content: 'gatsby, scratch, without CLI'}
                    ]}/>
            <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title}/>
            <main
                style={{
                    margin: '0 auto',
                    padding: 0
                }
                }>{children()}</main>
        </div>
    )
    else
        console.log("Empty")
}

export default Layout;

export const query = graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
            siteMetadata{
                title
            }
        }
    }
`
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

const Index = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>Gatsby project from scratch!</h1>
            <p>Creating Gatsby project without using CLI to better understand the machenics of generated files.</p>
            <Link to="/blog/">Blog</Link>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

What I tried and their observations :

- `gatsby clean` : same runtime error
- Tried removing `RouteHandler` this gives me a blank page

I may be missing something here, new pair of eyes may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `pnpm` with the project earlier, then today I deleted the `node_modules` and did `yarn install`, then ran the app and mentioned runtime error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

`pnpm install @reach/router@1.3.4` solved this for me

gatsby version 4.21.1

EDIT

`pnpm v7` ended up solving this when i ran `pnpm install`

It was broken on `pnpm v6`
I did not need `@reach/router1.3.4`

Comment: I can't get this to work with pnpm 7.29.0 so reverting back to yarn for the mo.

Comment: @George the best answer is to get off gatsby completely and go to nextjs